# How to change a value in the Jtextfield or JComboBox using the data structure linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list

I already used the set method in a LinkedList to change a value but it is not working for me. Everytime it will print the values in the console, it results to the same values. It doesn't change at all. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 0; i < emp.id.size(); i++){
                if(emp.id.get(i).equals(textField_6.getText())){
                    Employee emp = new Employee();

                    emp.setFirstname(textField_1.getText());
                    emp.setLastname(textField_2.getText());
                    emp.setAge(textField_3.getText());
                    emp.setGender(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                    emp.setDesignation(comboBox_4.getSelectedItem());


                    emp.fName.set(i, emp.getFirstname());
                    emp.LName.set(i, emp.getLastname());
                    emp.Age.set(i, emp.getAge());
                    emp.Gender.set(i, emp.getGender());
                    emp.Designation.set(i, emp.getDesignation());
                }
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully changed!");

            System.out.println(emp.id);
            System.out.println(emp.fName);
            System.out.println(emp.LName);
            System.out.println(emp.Age);
            System.out.println(emp.Gender);
            System.out.println(emp.Designation);

            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

            if(cmd.equals("Update")){
                dispose();
                exit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

You are not updating an existing object, you are creating a new object and you never all the object to the LinkedList.

```
if(emp.id.get(i).equals(textField_6.getText())){
```

You have the if condition to find the "emp" object you want to update, so use that object.

Comment: how will i do it?

Comment: @PatriciaOrtega maybe I don't understand your data structure, but you search to find the object with the correct matching name. Did you add a System.out.println(...) statement to make sure the if statement is ever true? If so then just use the object found in the if statement.